# how to use my own subclass of a swing class in griffon

Tags: swing, groovy, jtable, griffon

I need to use my own subclass of JTable, but not sure how I would use it in the View, could not find it anywhwere.

What do I have to use instead of table here:

```
scrollPane (constraints: "growx, growy, gapy 0:0:0, gapx 0:0:0") {
                table(id: 'thesublcass') {
                    tableFormat = defaultTableFormat(columns: model.columns)
                    ...
                }
}
```

EDIT: this worked perfectly, thanks both.

> table(new YourClass())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `widget` as shown towards the bottom of this page:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/SwingBuilder+with+custom+widgets+and+observer+pattern

ie:

```
            widget( new YourClass(), id: 'thesublcass') {
                tableFormat = defaultTableFormat(columns: model.columns)
                ...
            }
```

Comment: thanks! I tried that but I get 'java.lang.RuntimeException: 'widget' doesn't support nesting.'...is there a way to include the tableFormat settinge etc inside the widget()??

Comment: You could create an instance of your class, set it up, then pass this instance to `widget`

Comment: As noted `widget` does not support nesting but `container` does, as explained in http://griffon.codehaus.org/guide/latest/guide/views.html#specialNodes. You can also use `table(new YourClass())` as long as YourClass is a subclass of JTable.